# How to assign the radius value for the dynamically created circle in paper.js

Tags: javascript, graphics, paperjs

I want to draw a circle like in paint, if the mousedown means it takes the point and if dragging the mouse means the radius of the circle should be increased accordingly, can anyone help me

Comment: on `mousedown` log the point where the mouse was clicked. On `mouseup` log the point where the mouse was up. The math becomes pretty simple to find the direct line between these 2 points - which is your circle radius

Comment: thank u.. i understood @ Nicholas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the *distance* between the mouse downpoint and the current mouse position.

Then use that distance as the *radius* of your circle.

Here's some code that does just that:

```
function onMouseDrag(event) {
    var trackingCircle = new Path.Circle({
        position: event.downPoint, 
        radius: event.downPoint.subtract(event.point).length,
        dashArray: [2, 2],
        strokeColor: 'red'
    })

    trackingCircle.removeOn({
        drag: true,
        down: true,
        up:true
    })
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    var circle = new Path.Circle({
        position: event.downPoint, 
        radius: event.downPoint.subtract(event.point).length,
        strokeColor: 'black'
    })
}
```

and here's the actual [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.11.8/S/xVI9a8MwEP0rh5bEYDRkFHQo6VoaCJ2SDLJ0tYWdk9GHQwn+75XsurR1994g0NO79+4eujOSV2SCHVsMqmElU1bn+1skFYwlsPRso8cnJ+stDkihgPuZzmGQDoKTqjVU741THcIDEN7gIEPDZ2Q7MSFVb73JcgImDa7tjQ7WUChhoTipTfQrAvexyj5hdud9BgveIdWhKZdmLX3z6Jx8F3DalbC7pBf4LB+cbXFvO+sEbBzqTe4ai3ROnJ9bcIdXO+AL5eEXCZ22F4kY8ZtuHnEFxl5kZAayx5htfqf52q+yVP+Y4d9JVV3K5SurMf2NyqFsp2bPxOkyfgA=), (click-and-drag on the canvas).